# I am trying to create a Postgres DB using CloudFormation

Tags: postgresql

I am new in CloudFormation.

I am trying to create a Postgres DB using CloudFormation.
I am getting the following error:

***"Given input did not match expected format"***

You help would be highly appreciated.

Below is my CF code:

Comment: I think you forgot to add the code.

Comment: do you ever figure this out? Im getting the same error w/ my Lambda functions using CF

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "DevOps COE basic Postgres RDS Template",
    "Parameters": {
        "PrivateSubnetAZ1A": {
            "Default": "subnet-f9db67c8",
            "Description": "(REQUIRED) CIDR Block for the private subnet 1 located in Availability Zone 1",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "PrivateSubnetAZ1B": {
            "Default": "subnet-2fd8fb21",
            "Description": "(REQUIRED) CIDR Block for the private subnet 1 located in Availability Zone 2",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "DBName": {
            "Default": "RDSPostgreSQLInstance",
            "Description": "The Postgres database name",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "DBUsername": {
            "Default": "'{{resolve:secretsmanager:SonarQubePostgresPWD2:SecretString:username}}'",
            "NoEcho": "true",
            "Description": "The Postgres database admin account username",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "DBPassword": {
            "Default": "'{{resolve:secretsmanager:SonarQubePostgresPWD2:SecretString:password}}'",
            "NoEcho": "true",
            "Description": "The database admin account password",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "DBClass": {
            "Default": "db.m1.large",
            "Description": "Database instance class",
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "db.t2.micro",
                "db.m1.small",
                "db.m1.large",
                "db.m1.xlarge",
                "db.m2.xlarge",
                "db.m5.large"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must select a valid database instance type."
        },
        "DBAllocatedStorage": {
            "Default": "50",
            "Description": "The size of the database (GiB)",
            "Type": "Number",
            "MinValue": "5",
            "MaxValue": "1024",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 20 and 65536 GiB."
        },
        "DaysDBBackupsStored":{
            "Description":"The number of days for which automated backups are retained. Setting this parameter to a positive number enables backups.  Setting this parameter to 0 disables automated backups.\n",
            "Type":"Number",
            "Default":7
        },
        "DBMonitoringInSeconds":{
            "Description":"The interval, in seconds, between points when Enhanced Monitoring metrics are collected for the DB instance.",
            "Type":"Number",
            "Default":60
        },
        "DBStorageType":{
            "Description":"Specifies the storage type to be associated with the DB instance. General Purpose SSD storage offers cost-effective storage  that is acceptable for most database workloads.\n",
            "Type":"String",
            "Default":"gp2"
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "VPC": {
            "defaultVpc": {
                "Id": "vpc-dcb633a1"
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "DevOpsDBEC2SecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Frontend Access",
                "VpcId": {
                    "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "VPC",
                        "defaultVpc",
                        "Id"
                    ]
                },
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 5432,
                    "ToPort": 5432,
                    "CidrIp": "10.128.81.0/25"
                }]
            }
        },
        "DevOpsDBParamGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "Database Parameter Group + pg_stat_statements",
                "Family": "aurora-postgresql12",
                "Parameters": {
                    "shared_preload_libraries": "pg_stat_statements"
                }
            }
        },
        "DevOpsDBSubnetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "DB Private Subnet",
                "SubnetIds": [{
                        "Ref": "PrivateSubnetAZ1A"
                    },
                    {
                        "Ref": "PrivateSubnetAZ1B"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "RDSPostgreSQLInstance":{
            "Type":"AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "Properties":{
                "AllocatedStorage":"Ref DBAllocatedStorage",
                "BackupRetentionPeriod":"Ref DaysDBBackupsStored",
                "DBInstanceClass":"Ref DBClass",
                "DBName":"Ref DBName",
                "DBSubnetGroupName":"Ref DevOpsDBEC2SecurityGroup",
                "DeleteAutomatedBackups":true,
                "Engine":"postgres",
                "MasterUsername":"Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', Ref RDSInstanceSecrets, ':SecretString:username}}' ]]",
                "MasterUserPassword":"Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', Ref RDSInstanceSecrets, ':SecretString:password}}' ]]",
                "MonitoringInterval":"Ref DBMonitoringInSeconds",
                "StorageType":"Ref DBStorageType",
                "MultiAZ" : true,
                "VPCSecurityGroups":[
                    "Ref DevOpsDBEC2SecurityGroup"
                ]
            }
        },
.
.
.
```